# delete duplicate row on table

Tags: mysql, sql

i have table named etablissement_amenities

```
id
etablissement_id
amenities_id
```

I need to delete my duplicate row.
For example I have duplicate row like this.

```
id         etablissement_id          amenities_id
1          1                          1
2          1                          1
3          2                          2
4          6                          3
5          6                          3
```

I have duplicate my table and I have try this request

```
DELETE FROM doublon 
WHERE id < ANY (SELECT etablissement_amenities.id 
                FROM doublon, etablissement_amenities 
                WHERE doublon.id = etablissement_amenities.id 
                AND doublon.amenities_id = etablissement_amenities.amenities_id 
                AND doublon.etablissement_id = etablissement_amenities.etablissement_id);
```

But I have an error

```
You can't specify target table 'doublon' for update in FROM clause
```

Anybody can help me ?

Thanks you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This Query Will hopefuly delete all duplicated rows from `doublon`

```
DELETE FROM doublon  WHERE id in 
( Select id  from `doublon` where `id` not in
    ( Select id
         From `doublon` 
         group  by etablissement_id,amenities_id
         having Count(etablissement_id) > 1  and Count(amenities_id) > 1
         union
      Select id
         From `doublon` 
         group  by etablissement_id,amenities_id
         having Count(etablissement_id) = 1  and Count(amenities_id) = 1
     )
 )
```

Here is for duplicate records **[sqlfiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/be63b/52)**

Comment: You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '*) > 1)' at line 1

Comment: @dutycorpse :  i have updated my answer check it   and let me know

Comment: @dutycorpse the inner Select query will get doublicate records with count and the outer select will select only id and will be deleted

Comment: Now Unknown column 'temp.etablissement_amenities.id' in 'field list'

Comment: just remove temp before etablissement and check

Comment: Same error :  Unknown column 'etablissement_amenities.id' in 'field list'

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/72854/discussion-between-khurram-ali-and-dutycorpse).

Answer (score 0):

You cannot use the same table again in a `delete` or `update` in MySQL.  Instead, just use a `join`:

```
DELETE ea
    FROM etablissement_amenities ea JOIN
         (select ea.etablissement_id, MIN(ea.id) as minid
          from etablissement_amenities ea
          group by ea.etablissement_id
         ) ead
         on ea.etablissement_id = ead.etablissement_id and
            ea.id > ead.minid;
```

I have no idea what `doublon` is.  Your problem statement only mentions one table, `etablissement_amenities`.

Comment: Doublon is etablisement_amenities table duplicate

Comment: Unknown column 'ead.etablissemen_id' in 'on clause'

Comment: There is no `etablissemen_id` in the query.  There was an incorrect reference to `minid`, which I just fixed.

Comment: Same error: #1054 - Unknown column 'ead.etablissement_id' in 'on clause'

Answer (score 0):

There is no information about the table doublon  u refered in the above query.

To delete or update a table with sub query referencing same table, try enclosing the subquery in a temporary derived table as follows.

```
DELETE FROM doublon 
WHERE   id < ANY (Select * from (SELECT etablissement_amenities.id 
                FROM doublon, etablissement_amenities 
                WHERE doublon.id = etablissement_amenities.id 
                AND doublon.amenities_id = etablissement_amenities.amenities_id 
                AND doublon.etablissement_id = etablissement_amenities.etablissement_id) as Tmp);
```

`P.s. The answer is to fix the error in above query. It is not about deleting duplicate values.....`